# Formatting in a textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to format my textbox to have 4 numerical integers at all times. Example 90 would equal 0090. I also do not want letters to be entered. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is this WinForms or Web?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like a [Masked Textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)? You can use a [mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) of "0000" to ensure only numbers can be entered, and that you need four of them.

If it's for asp.net you could look at a [MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/maskededit/maskededit.aspx) or a [jQuery](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) solution.

Comment: textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:0000}", someNumber); This is the way I have it I am new to C# a huge leap for me from Visual Basic

Comment: Is one of the rare occasions where a masked textbox is useful (often, it is too limited).